# How to test ApiController with XUnit Test in .netCore

Tags: .net, testing, xunit, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm wandering what is the best practice to Test Api Controller with xUnit Test in .Net Core. Input parameter should be json file for Insert and Update. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The best practices are well described in official doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Yes I already checked there but there is nothing for Json input parameter  :(. And I have no experience with Xunit